# Show that two intervals are equipotent

Tags: real-analysis

Show that any two non-degenerate intervals of a real numbers are equipotent. I know that the intervals can be open or closed. My question is Do i have to show that these two intervals has a relations meaning reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Comment: No, equipotent means that they have the same number of elements, that has nothing to do with reflexitivity, symmetry or transitivity of relations (and it's not clear what those would mean for a relation between different sets). - And some hours ago, another question was posted, that dealt with the difficult case, and it the comments to that was a link to a question that yours is a duplicate of.

Comment: I guess you're thinking about "equivalent", which is different from "equipotent".

Comment: no It is equipotent, i look in dictionaries to know what that means so far i have no luck, then i was trying to find it in my real analysis book nothing there also. that is why i post the question because i can not prove the statement because i do not know what to look for to begin with